# How to pass value from Dispatcher or Task to outside?

Tags: c#, asynchronous, task, dispatcher, async-await

Could anyone please help me passing the variable among tasks?

I ran into a trouble about to Dispatcher.RunAsync(). I declare the variable RssItem as the type of RSSItem.
I'm trying to pass the value of RssItem returned by await m_RSSReader.CreateRSSItem() inside Dispatcher.RunAsync(...) to outside for assignment m_RssItemList.Add(RssItem);.

```
RSSItem RssItem;
// Save Individual RSS items as RSSItem
foreach (SyndicationItem item in CurrentFeed.Items)
{
    //RssItem = new RSSItem();
    // by using dispatcher, it resolves the issue of lagging UI
    await Dispatcher.RunAsync(Windows.UI.Core.CoreDispatcherPriority.Normal, async () =>
        {
            RssItem = await m_RSSReader.CreateRSSItem(item.Links[0].Uri, m_CurrentRSSDataGroup, item, CurrentFeed);
        });

        if (RssItem != null)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine("RssItem Title : {0}", RssItem.Title);
            m_RssItemList.Add(RssItem);
        }
}
```

[7/11/12]
RSSItem is a class I create for storage. I use Dispatcher.RunAsync() to avoid interruption of UI, method m_RSSReader.CreateRSSItem() will return the class I want (RSSItem RssItem). but I need to pass it to outside of the Dispatcher task and add RssItem to the List (m_RssItemList.Add(RssItem). But I have trouble passing RssItem outside the Dispatcher.

Thank you,

Comment: What exactly is the problem? What does your code do?

Comment: RSSItem is a class I create for storage. I use Dispatcher.RunAsync() to avoid interruption of UI, method m_RSSReader.CreateRSSItem() will return the class I want (RSSItem RssItem). but I need to pass it to outside of the Dispatcher task and add RssItem to the List (m_RssItemList.Add(RssItem). But I have trouble passing RssItem outside the Dispatcher.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know if you solved it using `Task.Run` instead, but if you *do* want to wait for a `dispatcher.RunAsync`, you can also use a `WaitHandle`, for instance a `ManualResetEvent`. For some reason the `RunAsync` call continues without actually "awaiting". The waithandle takes care of that.

```
// assign to null, since it will be "unassigned" otherwise
RssItem rssItem = null;
EventWaitHandle waithandle = new ManualResetEvent(false);
await Dispatcher.RunAsync(Windows.UI.Core.CoreDispatcherPriority.Normal, async () =>
{
    rssItem = await m_RSSReader.CreateRSSItem(item.Links[0].Uri, m_CurrentRSSDataGroup, item, CurrentFeed);
    waithandle.Set();
});

waithandle.WaitOne();
if (rssItem != null)
{
    Debug.WriteLine("RssItem Title : {0}", rssItem.Title);
    m_RssItemList.Add(rssItem);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't think `Dispatcher.RunAsync` does what you think it does.

I believe what you're looking for is `Task.Run`, something like this:

```
RssItem = await Task.Run(() =>
   m_RSSReader.CreateRSSItem(item.Links[0].Uri, m_CurrentRSSDataGroup, item, CurrentFeed)
);
```

Comment: Thanks. I tried that, but I actually need Dispatcher.RunAsync() to add UI element dynamically. Method CreateRSSItem() will adds UI element.

Comment: Then you have to do it on the UI thread. `Dispatcher` won't help you at all in your situation.